# How come when I use htmlentities() on my wamp server it works well, but has weird characters on someone else's server?

Tags: php

I'm pulling an XML feed that doesn't specify the encoding. I can't change this on the feed.
When I use htmlentities(), it gives me a proper output for certain characters on my WAMP server, but when I upload it to another server, it seems like the encoding is incorrect for certain characters, like open and close double quotes (not just " but the one that looks like 66 and 99)

Comment: Any examples of this strange encoded XML ?

Comment: If you are using different versions of PHP, the third argument for htmlenties will be different. That could be what is causing the difference. Taken from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php): `If omitted, the default value for this argument is ISO-8859-1 in versions of PHP prior to 5.4.0, and UTF-8 from PHP 5.4.0 onwards`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone else's server may have different encoding. You can specify the encoding to be compatible with someone else's server.

> Like `htmlspecialchars()`, `htmlentities()` takes an optional third argument encoding which defines encoding used in conversion. If omitted, the default value for this argument is ISO-8859-1 in versions of PHP prior to 5.4.0, and UTF-8 from PHP 5.4.0 onwards.

[See the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)